# Can't scan video with video cursor or set currentTime with popcorn

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, webm, popcornjs

I'm using [popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) for the first time and I'm having a blast with it.  I have two problems that seem to be related.  I have a six minute video showing off a bike route with all kinds of popcorn.js fun along the way.

I'd like to include buttons that users can click to bounce to certain parts of the route.  I found some sample code somewhere in the documentation that looks like this.

```
<button onclick="monroeTime()" type="button">Go to Monroe</button>
<script>
    myVid = document.getElementById("skunk-creek");

    function getCurTime() {
        alert(myVid.currentTime);
    }

    function monroeTime() {
        myVid.currentTime = 150;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is I'm able to jump ahead to no further than 150 seconds.  If I change that variable to 151 or higher it doesn't work but my video is 365 seconds long.

On a related note, I'm not able to grab the video timeline cursor and change the time. When I do, the video freezes and the page needs to be refreshed.

Here is the page I'm working on. Note it's only set up for Chrome at this time.  Also I haven't created an MP4 file yet as my video editing software doesn't create mp4's.

http://richpoints.com/b-path/

What do I need to do to make navigate this video timeline?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with your webm video file, not with the script. It's not a problem with your web server either, as byte serving seems to be working just fine. You can test this by opening the video file itself in your browser, directly from the file system. The same problem happens, independent of any web page or Javascript.

It looks like you encoded the file with libebml and libmatroska. WebM is a subset of Matroska, so VLC plays it just fine, but the browser is not able to seek. Try encoding with libvpx instead.